# How to add custom tooltip items to Apexcharts?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, apexcharts

I am using ApexChart and I would like to add som more info to the tooltip (that shows on hover). I have read the documentation but I really don´t understand how to do it.

My problem is that I don't understand where I should add that extra data and how I can make it show in the tooltip?

Right now I only see the default in the tooltip, which is the name of the series and "y" value. I would like to see:

- **Price**: (x value)
- **Number**: (y value)
- **Product**: 'name',
- **Info**: 'info',
- **Site**: 'name'

How can I add this to the tooltip? This is what I got so far:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9m0r2ont/1/

Code:

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    height: 380,
    width: "100%",
    type: "scatter",
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Series 1",
      data: [
        {
          x: 100,
          y: 50,
          product: 'name',
          info: 'info',
          site: 'name'
        },
        {
          x: 150,
          y: 55,
          product: 'name',
          info: 'info',
          site: 'name'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  xaxis: {
    type: "numeric"
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
var options = {
  chart: {
    height: 380,
    width: "100%",
    type: "scatter",
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Series 1",
      data: [
        {
          x: 100,
          y: 50,
          product: 'name',
          info: 'info',
          site: 'name'
        },
        {
          x: 150,
          y: 55,
          product: 'name',
          info: 'info',
          site: 'name'
        },
        {
          x: 130,
          y: 44,
          product: 'name',
          info: 'info',
          site: 'name'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  xaxis: {
    type: "numeric"
  },
  tooltip: {
    custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
      var data = w.globals.initialSeries[seriesIndex].data[dataPointIndex];
      
      return '<ul>' +
      '<li><b>Price</b>: ' + data.x + '</li>' +
      '<li><b>Number</b>: ' + data.y + '</li>' +
      '<li><b>Product</b>: \'' + data.product + '\'</li>' +
      '<li><b>Info</b>: \'' + data.info + '\'</li>' +
      '<li><b>Site</b>: \'' + data.site + '\'</li>' +
      '</ul>';
    }
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chart">
</div>
```

To do this, you need to add a [custom tooltip](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/#custom) to the `options` object. Access the `w` object passed into the function to get the correct data. They have a similar example [here](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/NBdyvV). Once you can identify the data you're interested in within that object, use it to return the HTML to show in the tooltip.

Comment: w.globals, yikes... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `renderToString` function from react-dom/server to render the tooltip content without needing to define it as a string:

```
  tooltip: {
    custom: function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
      var data = w.globals.initialSeries[seriesIndex].data[dataPointIndex];    
      return renderToString(<>custom TSX component</>);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Note I'm using APEX chart type box plot

1. Go to the charts Attributes and under advanced you will see 'JavaScript Initialization Code' in that you will include this code

```js
function(options) {
    options.tooltip = {
        renderer: function(context) {  
            var high = Math.round(context.data.high);
            var median = Math.round(context.data.q2);  
            var low = Math.round(context.data.low);
 
            var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');
 
            var tooltipContent = 'High: ' + formatter.format(high) + '\n' +
                                 'Median: ' + formatter.format(median) + '\n' +
                                 'Low: ' + formatter.format(low);
 
            return tooltipContent;
        }
    };
    
    return options;
}
```

Make sure tooltip is enabled for the chart.
Some documentation I found helpful - https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/

Hopefully this helps!